# How to check COM dll is registered or not with C#?

Tags: c#, registry

I need to check if msdia100.dll is registered on a computer system that I'm running in order to register the dll with the command `regsvr32.exe`. How can I do that with C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can search through the registry for this. Assuming that you don't know the COM objects contained in the DLL you'll have to start looking for the DLL name first in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`.

Then use the class name to find the CLSID in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\[ClassName]\CLSID` and finally you should be able find it the CLSID as `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\[CLSID]`.

Please note, registry locations written from memory so might be a bit off.

Edit: Or if you know the class name you could just try to create an instance of it and see if it works or not.

Answer (score 4):

The registry approaches are okay and worth doing, but to be sure you might also consider instantiating something from within the COM object wrapped in a try {} catch (COMException) {}, then present something sensible to the user if a COMException got caught.

Comment: Particularly since the registry is a lot more complicated than it looks, due to various layers of emulation, 32/64-bit and so on.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you know the CLSID of the COM dll, you can just check if there's a key with that CLSID on `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{CLSID-of-your-COM-component}` or `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{CLSID-of-your-COM-component}` (Wow6432Node => 32-bit COM registered on a 64-bit machine)

e.g.

```
private bool IsAlreadyRegistered()
{
    using (var classesRootKey = Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(
           Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.ClassesRoot, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryView.Default))
    {
        const string clsid = "{12345678-9012-3456-7890-123456789012}";

        var clsIdKey = classesRootKey.OpenSubKey(@"Wow6432Node\CLSID\" + clsid) ??
                        classesRootKey.OpenSubKey(@"CLSID\" + clsid);

        if (clsIdKey != null)
        {
            clsIdKey.Dispose();
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Verify if key exists using Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey

```
var key = Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(
            Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.ClassesRoot,
            Microsoft.Win32.RegistryView.Default)
            .OpenSubKey("Interface")
               //replace with your COM object GUID
            .OpenSubKey("{a3560000-0000-0000-c63b3-000000cbadf0000}");

        return key != null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the rgistry at HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\\InprocServer. If you have that record, then the DLL should be registered.

Answer (score -1):

This is the proper way to do it. It does involve PInvoke but that' only because they haven't provided this capability in .NET directly.

```
[DllImport("kernel32")]    
public extern static int LoadLibrary(string lpLibFileName);

[DllImport("kernel32")]    
public extern static bool FreeLibrary(int hLibModule);        

public bool IsDllRegistered(string DllName)    
{    
  int libId = LoadLibrary(DllName);
  if (libId>0) FreeLibrary(libId);
  return (libId>0);    
}
```

Comment: I don't believe this is at all correct. It loads *any* DLL, regardless of whether it's registered as hosting a COM object.

Comment: @Steve, you're loading a dll by name and not a full path. If the dll loads it has been registered. If not, it has not been registered. Unless the dll you're looking for also happens to be in your path.

Comment: Just to be clear, LoadLibrary followed by DllGetClassObject (with CLSID and IID of the interface) gives you and instance of a COM object you can play with. If load library fails, it's not going to work, period.

Comment: If the DLL loads, it's because the DLL was found on the path. If you drop the DLL into the current directory or into C:\Windows\System32 or anywhere else it can be found, then LoadLibrary will work. At that point, so will DllGetClassObject, but this tells us nothing. Whoever upvoted you was mistaken.